# How did Leia enter the ship without killing everyone?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi*, after

> Leia gets blasted out of the ship and uses the force to enter it again, a door opens and she enters a non air locked area.

How does she re-enter the ship without exposing it to space and killing everybody?

I think that this was a major realism mistake and I am hoping that there is an explanation for it!

Comment: They can all somehow breathe in space, see e.g. asian bomber woman in the beginning. On the other hand, if it was space, how did the bombs drop onto the dreadnought when there is no gravity... or when Kylo fires missiles and everything explodes and Poe gets thrown around, but somehow there is still atmosphere... god I hate that movie.

Comment: @ElDuderino if there are objects in space there is gravity in space how strong is another question, but yeah the rest still holds true

Comment: @ElDuderino True! Although they a little push coming from the mechanism of the bomber would be enough to send them straight down.

Comment: @papakias thinking about it if the bombs were just falling straight down into the explosion of the other bombs then wouldn't the bombs blow up/damaged on their decent?

Comment: @SCFi The bombs might even get pushed up from the first explosions and hit the bombers instead of the target. But these are minor faults in realism that I can accept.

Comment: "I think that this was a major realism mistake"  *Star Wars* is WW2 In Space... with magic.  Just turn off your brain and watch.

Comment: @RonJohn I don't agree with you. This is what makes a good movie. To create a universe and be able to support it.

Comment: Presumably for the same reason that all the people in hangars don't die? Forcefields separating air from vacuum are all over the place in Star Wars.

Comment: Didn't the battle take place near a planet?  There would be some gravity then wouldn't there?  The hangar doors opening with a bomber by them doesn't make a lot of sense though, but it was entertaining.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## There is a second door (which must have closed first), the camera angle just doesn't show it.

**(speculation unfortunately, I don't think there's a confirmed answer)**

These screenshots show the door before and after Leia enters the airlock. You can see that there's even a lighted button on the inside for closing the door.

[image]

[image]

I think it's safe to assume that someone closed that door before they opened the next one. It could have been a crew member pressing a remote button, or it could have even been Leia using the Force to press the button herself.

If it was a well-designed starship, this dual-door system would recognize the vacuum on one side, and only allow one door to open at a time. Perhaps when Poe (and others) opened the second door, it automatically caused the first door to close.

Comment: Toe was not over the line.  Mark it as an answer, Dude.

Comment: Also, vapor blew from Leia's side *into* the main ship when the door opened.  If the other side had been in vacuum, air would have blown out.

Comment: There are also shields that contain atmosphere, hence all of those open docking bays. I think Leia was safe as soon as she got back into the bridge.